# Rails Devise current_password removed during update

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

**view**

In my app,using devise gem user can edit the form with wrong password, error message will show and form can display

```html
 = form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f|
          - devise_error_messages!
          .form-horizontal
            .form-group
              = f.label :email, :class => "col-sm-4 control-label"
              .col-sm-5
                = f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, :class => "form-control"
              .minimum-password
                - if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation?
                  %div
                    Currently waiting confirmation for: #{resource.unconfirmed_email}
            .form-group
              = f.label :password, :class => "col-sm-4 control-label"
              .col-sm-5
                = f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", :class => "form-control"
                %i.pull-right
                  (leave blank if you don't want to change it)
            .form-group
              = f.label :password_confirmation, :class => "col-sm-4 control-label"
              .col-sm-5
                = f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", :class => "form-control"
            .form-group
              = f.label :current_password, :class => "col-sm-4 control-label"
              .col-sm-5
                = f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "off",  :class => "form-control"
            .center-align
              .actions
                = f.submit "Update",:class => " btn btn-primary"
                %br/
                = link_to "Back", :back
```

Problem is when I update the form with wrong password in current_password field,error message shown(current_password is invalid) but current_password label and password_field is getting removed.